# Where to put a Dockerfile in an R package

Tags: r, package, dockerfile, cran

A contributor has added a Dockerfile to my R package. When trying to upload it to CRAN, it gets flagged:

```
Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
'Dockerfile'
```

Is there a more appropriate placement for Dockerfiles within the library's directory structure?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave it in the top level directory.  Use the `.Rbuildignore` file to add an exclusion to the Dockerfile (and other non-standard files).

`.Rbuildignore` uses regex.  Here's an example `.Rbuildignore` file:

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
.travis.yml
.*.tar.gz
^local
```

Comment: Thanks, adding `^Dockerfile` to `.Rbuildignore` worked. In your example would that mean you are _not_ ignoring `.travis.yml` though?

Comment: No, the `^` character means "start of the file name" I think.